# WinForms Scrollbar, disable out-of-range scrolling. Should be manual?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I set the `Maximum` of a `VScrollBar` as the total number of rows, `LargeChange` as the number of rows that can be displayed. I thought out-of-range inputs will be handled by the scrollbar control, but it did not. It still raised "small decrement" or "thumbtrack" events when I tried to scroll up at the top (row =0, clicking the ^ button on the scroll bar, or trying to drag the thumb up), or the "large increment" event when the thumb is already at the bottom and I right click and choose "Page down".

I think I can check the conditions and the `OldValue`, `NewValue` to disable the out-of-range scrolls myself, but can't this be automatically done? Most programmers would not want the scrollbar going out of range, so I think it does not make sense that Microsoft did not implemented it, and maybe I just do not know how to enable it.

Comment: Are you referring to the standard [VScrollBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar) Control?. If that's the case, you receive `Scroll` events when you try to scroll past the minimum and maximum values, but the ValueChange event is not raised (since there's no change in value). Or are you referring to the [SCROLLINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-scrollinfo) structure?

Comment: @Jimi  The former, as I specifically mentioned the class's name. So, I should use the Value Changed event instead of Scroll event. Thanks. And, is it possible to disable the buttons on the scroll bar selectively? I mean, I want to disable the up button on the scroll bar when the thumb is already at the top.

Comment: For example: `If ([ScrollBar].Value >= ([ScrollBar].Maximum - [ScrollBar].LargeChange) { SendMessage([ScrollBar].Handle, SBM_ENABLE_ARROWS, ESB_DISABLE_DOWN, 0); }`. `SBM_ENABLE_ARROWS = 0x00E4`, `ESB_DISABLE_DOWN = 0x0002`.

Comment: Anyway, it's not really useful, since when you handle ValueChanged, when the scrollbar reaches its Minimum or (Maximum - LargeChange) + 1, the event is not raised anymore (while the Scroll event will keep on signaling that a scroll request has been queued).

Comment: So, the .NET API does not provide the ability to disable up/down buttons? I thought I had seen scrollbars that disabled the up/down button individually when scrolling up/down is not possible, but when I examined several applications in Windows, none of them seemed to be disabling those buttons individually... So, I guess I don't have to do that.

Comment: That code I posted does that exactly: it disables the Down Arrow of a vertical  ScrollBar (didn't you test it?). It's not *really useful*  to disable it when handling the ValueChanged event for the reason described.

Comment: What I meant is that it is not the .NET API, but calling Win32 API. I thought of disabling it as a visual cue saying "you cannot scroll up any more".